# Would this program be useful in cryptography?

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis, prime-numbers

I know nothing of encrypting. I'm not even sure how to tag this.
I wrote a program that can calculate this pretty quickly on my macbook pro 2.3GHz IntelCore i7. The two exponents are Mersenne primes, and no I did not use floats.

It calculated `((2^756839)-1) * ((2^1257787)-1)` = a number 606,463 digits long. The exponentiation, multiplication, and all took about a minute? Would it be good for encrypting? Maybe not those numbers specifically, but in general because it wouldn't require me to use a supercomputer. And yes, that is 606,463 digits long. So `prime*prime=N`, where N, aside from 1 and itself, is only divisible by the two primes. Don't know if it'd be useful at all, but I did it for fun, for something else. I'm going to try working on the reverse(factoring N).

Comment: I'm sorry to say the answer is almost certainly no. Multiplying large numbers is something that has been studied in depth over the years, and the odds are your program does not provide a breakthrough. In the particular case you've given, there seems to be a shortcut to solving it anyway

Comment: I don't understand your second point, however, I do your first. Can I not use it myself for encryption? I mean, I have that entire number stored in a text file. It's 606,463 digits long.

Comment: Working in binary notation (as your computer will be), $(2^{756839}-1)$ is the number given by 756839 consecutive 1's. Since $$(2^{756839}-1) * (2^{1257787}-1) = (2^{756839}-1)*2^{1257787} - 2^{756839} + 1$$
the answer will (in binary) have 756838 ones, followed by a single zero,followed by ~50100 ones, followed by 756839 zeros and then finally a 1. (nb: my counts may be out by +- a few, sorry, but the idea holds)

Comment: Have you tried running RSA on that number? By my estimation it'd take about a week for a single private key operation unless you implement advanced multiplication algorithms.

Comment: I realise this may be rather obvious, but just in case - even if you could run RSA private key with that modulus (which would be very difficult as CiC notes), the factorisation is here on crypto.SE, so anyone trying to break your system can just read off your factors from here!

Comment: @user8911: I know that, but it took about a minute to calculate, so I can always produce another key by multiplying 2 primes.

Comment: It's a fully functioning calculator that works fast with large numbers. I don't need to use those two mp's specifically, I can choose any other two and do the same if it's too long. I just don't know if it'd be helpful for anything, lol. I like finding shortcuts to things for fun, it's good practice.

Comment: Just as a benchmark, Mathematica was able to compute the above in 0.01 seconds (as measured by [Timing](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Timing.html)). My processor is an Intel i5-3570k at stock clock speeds.

Comment: How does Mathematica work? I thought numbers this large were too large to process or use, unless you have enough ram.

Comment: If nothing else, if your program can do it, then surely Mathematica can too? There are lots of different ways of representing numbers in a computer, some of which are more or less useful for different purposes. However, the authors of high performance mathematical software are sure to have picked one of the better ones. Either way, this is starting to drift further and further away from cryptography. You might find you have an appropriate question to ask on one of the other SE boards - eg [mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) or [programming](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @user2616745: Don't overestimate how much memory large numbers take up relative to the capacity of modern-day RAM. The two numbers you're multiplying only take up about 90 and 150 kilobytes, respectively... that's not much memory at all.

Comment: @user8911 You shouldn't just benchmark multiplication time. Part of key-gen with unknown primes is the primality test. You can't use well known primes like mersenne primes, those could be trivially factored. But just obtaining the key isn't the problem. You actually need to be able to sign/decrypt data with it. Even with karatsuba multiplication that will be pretty expensive. With numbers that size you need to use fancy algorithms, for example a fourier transform based one.

Comment: @owlstead: But is that an approximation? Or is it exact?

Comment: `time echo "((2^756839)-1) * ((2^1257787)-1)" | bc` calculates this in 33s, but that's on my sluggish laptop...

Comment: W|F gives a decimal approximation, I spoke with a representative. I'm asking around Mathematica, users on their stackexchange(very snappy), say it gives an exact answer. I emailed people from Mathematica and I'm waiting for them to respond.

Comment: @user2616745: I'm not sure why you need to message the Mathematica folks... the computation is very fast and produces an exact result. But don't let that discourage you, because there are some *very* smart folks working on Mathematica, and it leverages some *very* advanced mathematics. If you're wondering about methodology, maybe look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fast_multiplication_algorithms_for_large_inputs) -- but be aware that Mathematica may leverage situation-specific algorithms, if there are any well-known ones for this (I don't know offhand).

Answer (score 2):

I can several possible questions in the original post, hopefully I'll manage to answer at least one of them here.

---

**I have calculated a large $N$, with $\log_{10}(N)>600,000$. Is this suitable for RSA?**
We have that $\log_{10}(N)>6*10^5>2^{19}$, meaning $\log_2(N)>2^{19}$. Currently, implementations with $\log_2(N)\approx 2^{11}$ are coming into practice, making your choice of $N$ much much larger than those in use today. There's a nice little crypto.SE question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589850/2883315) stating that there is no need for $N$ orders of magnitude greater than $2^{2048}$, with good references.

**Is my multiplication algorithm good for taking the product of Mersenne Primes?** I'm sorry to say the answer is almost certainly no. Multiplying large numbers is something that has been studied in depth over the years, and the odds are your program does not provide a breakthrough. In the particular case you've given (Mersenne primes), there is an efficient way to solve it anyway, so I suspect your implementation isn't as efficient as it could be:

Working in binary notation (as your computer will be), $(2^{756839}-1)$ is the number given by 756839 consecutive 1's. Since $$(2^{756839}-1) * (2^{1257787}-1) = (2^{756839}-1)*2^{1257787} - 2^{756839} + 1$$
the answer will (in binary) have 756838 ones, followed by a single zero,followed by ~50100 ones, followed by 756839 zeros and then finally a 1. 
(nb: my counts may be out by $\pm1$, but the idea holds)

<sub>Part of this answer is drawn from my comments on the original post.</sub>

**Is my algorithm good for taking the product of two large integers?** I do not know the headline speeds for integer multiplication in general, but I'm pretty sure you should be able to do this a lot more quickly than you have, especially since your multiplication doesn't make use of the binary representation of its operands. You can easily test this by downloading reference code for Big Integer multiplication and timing yours against that. If you have a licence, Magma or Mathematica are both good candidates for a first test.
UPDATE: In the comments below, [Reid](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/2454/reid) provides benchmarking figures for Mathematica, demonstrating that your times are well off these, which should themselves be considered lower bounds.

Comment: Copying my comment from the original question: Just as a benchmark, Mathematica was able to compute the above in 0.01 seconds (as measured by [Timing](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Timing.html)). My processor is an Intel i5-3570k at stock clock speeds. This was on Mathematica 8. So, this benchmark shows just how much research has been poured into fast integer multiplication.

Comment: Actually, it seems 0.01 seconds is the slowest. Having run the test about a dozen more times, my (admittedly unscientific) result is that the above computation takes somewhere around 0.006 seconds on average, or about 6 milliseconds.

Comment: How does it give you the full answer? Is it just displayed? I thought you'd need a cracker-jack load of Ram. I'm on 8GB. I need to study more, lol.

Comment: @user2616745: Yep, it just gives me the answer in the prompt. [Here](https://rwiggins.net/bignum.pdf) is the notebook printed to a PDF (so this is pretty much exactly how the command shows up in the window, minus some minor styling differences). Edit: In fact, the bottleneck in Mathematica is actually writing the result to the notebook, not the computation itself... it visibly takes a second or so for the result to appear. But the computation itself (as you can see with `Timing`) doesn't take very long at all.

Comment: Hardcore computing!! I need to learn how to work in binary, or just learn more in general. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

If it only multiplies mersenne primes then likely not.

For now I can think of RSA, DSA and the Diffie–Hellman key exchange for its uses (They use prime numbers).

There are not enough mersenne primes for it to be used by itself. May be in can be used as part of a process. (Specialization).